# How to join other values not associated with the original

Tags: sql

I need to do this “Give me a list of the vendors we have used for any sort of design work and show all other vendors that are in the same state as them”
-This is not homework, This is a extra assignment I was given it has no grade.

```
Select InvoiceLineItemDescription From InvoiceLineItems
Where invoicelineitemdescription = ‘cover design’ 
(select InvoiceLineItemDescription from InvoiceLineItems Ili 
join invoices I on I.invoiceid = ili.invoiceid 
join vendors v on I.vendorid = v.vendorid where vendorname =“CA”)
```

My question is I am getting 2 tables showing up and also I can’t quite find a value unless I am “hardcoding” it in which I don’t want to do. Is their a better way to do this? It is only displaying Cover design and I want it to display every thing that is in the same state as cover design. AP database.

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for `UNION`? https://www.techonthenet.com/sql/union.php

Comment: Possibly, how would you determine the state without hardcoding it in though? Is their a function for that for it to see what Cover design is from and use that state and display all others from that state?